# jquery mobile table - detect change in select

Tags: jquery-mobile

My table contains a column that contains a "select".

I need to detect when the user changes the "select" value of the cell so I can make DOM changes to other cells in the row.

I have no idea how to detect that event.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Added an onchange to the html `<td>`.

Thanks;